# Disable designing role programmatically

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

I was wondering if there was any way to toggle/disable designer role from code. The desired effect from command: `webedit:toggledesigncapability`.

Image of command in page editor:

[image]

How can I toggle the designing capabilities from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below toggles the state of this setting for the current user. It should work for you or at least point you in the right direction. I didn't have time to test it so you need to do this on your own. Remember to refresh to page after you executed the code:

```cs
string key = "/Current_User/Page Editor/Capability/design";
if (Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry.GetString(key, "on") == "on")
{
    Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry.SetString(key, "off");
}
else
{
    if (WebEditUtil.CanDesignItem(Sitecore.Context.Item))
    {
        Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry.SetString(key, "on");
    }
}
```